# Reset or re-read stdin in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, stdin

I have some parsing scripts which accept input from either a file or `stdin` and parse them using pandas `read_csv`, which takes a file-like object as its input.

Sometimes the header differs, so I had it set up with try-except to try reading in the file, but if it fails to parse, then try with an alternative header specification.

This works for files, but if I use `stdin` as the input, it seems that the header line gets "consumed" by the first attempt at `read_csv`.

I am wondering if there is a way to buffer this line, or **reset `stdin` for a second attempt at parsing**, in a way that pandas will like.

Not sure example code will help, but:

```
if Opt.Args:
    FileName = Opt.Args[0]
    print >> sys.stderr, "READING from FILE",FileName
elif not sys.stdin.isatty():
    print >> sys.stderr, "READING from STDIN"
    FileName = sys.stdin

try:
    df = pd.read_csv(FileName,header=0,sep="\t", parse_dates=['RecordedDate'])
except ValueError:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(FileName,header=0,sep="\t",parse_dates=['RecordedDate_10'])
...etc...
```

Answer (score 3):

There's not one perfect way to "reset" stdin, at least not one which works across different operating systems. You could however try "rebinding" STDIN and it practically clears it.

> on unixoid systems, something like this could work:
>
> import sys
>   text = sys.stdin.read()
>   sys.stdin = open("/dev/tty")
>   sel = raw_input("Selection? : ")

Refer: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/467361

Comment: Would it be possible to do this on a Windows system?

Comment: The link to gossamer-threads seems to be spam - it forwards to https: slash slash www slash carbon60 dot com slash.
If you edit the answer and fix the link, you are welcome to delete my comment.